# In Spring-Data-JPA, can we annotate an Entity method such that it applies a where clause on a related collection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I know I can do the queries using a findXXX method in another class.  However I was wondering... is it possible to perform the query on the entity itself such that instead of invoking the "real method" it will perform a query instead when run in a JPA runtime?

e.g.

```
@Query("this.contracts where contracts.startDate <= :date and contracts.stopDate >= :date)
Set<Contract> activeContracts(LocalDate date) {
  return contracts
    .stream()
    .filter(c->c.isActive(date))
    .toSet();
}
```

From what I can tell it's not supported by the standard and the Hibernate `@Where` clause limits the entire entity not just the single method.

However, from what I can tell, the only performant way to do this assuming the related collection is large is to create a separate repository method like

```java
@Query("""
  from Contract contract
  where contract.startDate <= :date 
    and contract.stopDate >= :date
    and contract.container = :container
  """)
Set<Contract> activeContractsForContainer(Container container, LocalDate date);
```